# c# web service stored procedure parameter size issue

Tags: c#, web-services, size, truncate

I have a c# web service method which takes string array containing the Base64-encoded strings of the images and sends them to a SQL stored procedure. The code as follows;

```
[WebMethod]
public void APP_SikayetFoto_Set(string [] fotoByteArray)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Connection string";
    sqlConn.Open();//baglantı kurulur

    string FileName;
    for (int i = 0; i < fotoByteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        FileName = "C://Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/BWS/log.txt";
        StreamWriter obj;
        obj = new StreamWriter(FileName);
        obj.WriteLine(fotoByteArray[i]);
        obj.Close();


        SqlCommand spcmd = new SqlCommand("APP_SikayetFoto_Set", sqlConn);
        spcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        spcmd.Parameters.Add("@fotoByteArray", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = fotoByteArray[i];

        spcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    sqlConn.Close();

}
```

On the database side, I have allocated varchar(max) column for the image strings to be stored. But I can see that the string is truncated to 43679 characters which is not the full image string size. But on the log.txt file, I can see the full image string is being written correctly, without any truncate.

So I would suspect the problem is with "spcmd.Parameters.Add" section of my code but setting it to accept varchar(max) like

```
spcmd.Parameters.Add("@fotoByteArray", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = fotoByteArray[i];
```

wouldn't helped either. Any help would be much appreciated

**UPDATE**

OK I find the problem. There is nothing wrong with the stored procedure and the web service sending data to it. No limitations to string parameters either. The thing was, for the huge strings, SQL Management Studio limits them to 8192 chars to grid when doing the select statement. Thus, copying and pasting it somewhere else only gets 8192 chars. So, I pre-assumed that's all had been inserted. But when you query with using "len()" you get the actual length of the huge string and calling selection procedure from third party application takes the full string without any problem.

Comment: Why is your parameter size explicitly -1?

Comment: what was the expected string size? are you sure you're comparing the correct line in the log file? as a side-note: it may have been more efficient to use `varbinary` - then you wouldn't need to base-64 encode; but that probably isn't important

Comment: @Bigiansen because that's how you spell "max"; if this is a `varchar(max)`, then that is correct

Comment: can we reasonable assume that there's no chance that `APP_SikayetFoto_Set` did something silly here? it is actually `max` in the SP, and it doesn't do any string manipulation, right?